# Windows 10 Upgrade - Check Failed but Good to Go

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade my Windows 8.1 machine to Windows 10, but the check says my computer is not compatible. But when I click on the technical report, it says I'm good to go. I'm so confused. I've gotten Windows update to download Windows 10 several times but I think it errors out when it gets this confusing report:

[image]

When I click on "View Report"
[image]

**Does anyone know how to completely reset this and run the test again?** I've already tried:

> C:\Windows\system32>schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

and it doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can install it manually using the Media Tool and still get the free upgrade:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install